# Excel VBA Find/Highlight, but check value of adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

### REVISION AT BOTTOM

I have the following code which we use to search large excel documents for a list of numbers, and if found, highlight the cell.  The numbers are stored in a separate excel document, hence the "For i = # to ##" and "With Workbookx("$$$$").Sheets("%%%%")", where the symbols are to be replaced dependent on what documents they're using this macro for:

```
Sub PNsToRemove()

    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim findStr As String
    Dim ws      As Worksheet
    Dim lColor    As Long
    
    lColor = RGB(211, 211, 211)
    
    'Set i = # to ### to the first and last row numbers of the P/N list
    For i = # To ###

        'set $$$$$ to name of the excel sheet containing the pn's
        'set %%%%% to the sheet name that the pn's are on
            With Workbooks("$$$$$").Sheets("%%%%%")

                'set @ to the column that contains the pn's
                findStr = .Range("@" & i).Value
                
            End With
            
            For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("&&&&").Range("A:Z"), Sheets("&&&&").UsedRange)

            If InStr(cell.Value, findStr) > 0 Then
                cell.Interior.Color = lColor

            End If

            Next
    Next
            
End Sub
```

I had a situation arise the other day where before highlighting the cell, I need to check the value of a cell adjacent to it.  It will be on the same row, but between 1 and 3 columns to the left.  There is a list of strings that if present in the adjacent cell should keep the macro from highlighting the cell containing the number.  I suspect it will be a bit of code present in `If InStr(cell.value, findStr) > 0 Then` conditional, but am unsure how to proceed.

Thanks!
Jamie

### REVISION

I was able to get this to work for the value in prefix1, but 2 thru 4 won't work (Thanks for the comment on cell.offset() Siddharth!).  Am i missing something with the InStr function?  Everything I've read says it should work fine for numerical searches:

```
            prefix1 = "DG"
            prefix2 = "70"
            prefix3 = "72"
            prefix4 = "73"

            For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("CAT. NO.").Range("I:BO"), Sheets("CAT. NO.").UsedRange)

            If InStr(cell.Value, findStr) > 0 Then


                If InStr(cell.Offset(-1).Value, prefix1) = 0 Then
                If InStr(cell.Offset(-1).Value, prefix2) = 0 Then
                                'debug1 = InStr(cell.Offset(-1).Value, prefix1)
                                'Range("U6604").Value = debug1
                If InStr(cell.Offset(-1).Value, "72") = 0 Then
                If InStr(cell.Offset(-1).Value, "73") = 0 Then
                     cell.Interior.Color = lColor
                     cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Interior.Color = lColor
                     cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Interior.Color = lColor
                     cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Interior.Color = lColor
                     

                End If
                End If
                End If
                End If

            End If
```

I did have all the If statements in an If/And line, but it was easier to work with broken out.

Thanks!

Comment: to check adjacent cell (1 on the left), use `cell.Offset(,-1)`, for 2 on left use, `cell.Offset(,-2)` and so on

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED

Not really sure how your `# to ##` is working - there'll undoubtedly be a better way to add those numbers in dynamically, but that's outside the scope of this question so I'll ignore.

Try wrapping your `if` statement in a select case:

```
Sub PNsToRemove()

    Dim i       As Integer
Dim findStr As String
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim lColor    As Long
Dim chkStr1 As String, chkStr2 As String, chkStr3 As String

chkStr1 = "Check for this"
chkStr2 = "Or For This"
chkStr3 = "Or Even for This"

lColor = RGB(211, 211, 211)

'Set i = # to ### to the first and last row numbers of the P/N list
For i = # To ###

    'set $$$$$ to name of the excel sheet containing the pn's
    'set %%%%% to the sheet name that the pn's are on
        With Workbooks("$$$$$").Sheets("%%%%%")

            'set @ to the column that contains the pn's
            findStr = .Range("@" & i).Value

        End With

        For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("sheet1").Range("A:Z"), Sheets("sheet1").UsedRange)
            Select Case (cell)
                Case cell.Offset(0, 1) = chkStr1, chkStr2, chkStr3
                    GoTo MoveOn
                Case cell.Offset(0, 2) = chkStr1, chkStr2, chkStr3
                    GoTo MoveOn
                Case cell.Offset(0, 3) = chkStr1, chkStr2, chkStr3
                    GoTo MoveOn
                Case Else
                    If InStr(cell.Value, findStr) > 0 Then
                        cell.Interior.Color = lColor
                    End If
            End Select
MoveOn:
            Next
        Next

End Sub
```

We declare and assign string variables for the strings you're checking against at the top.

We check the case that one cell to the left matches any of the check strings - if so we duck out of the select case and move on to the next cell with no action, or else we move to the next case.

We check the case that two cell to the left matches any of the check strings - if so we duck out of the select case and move on to the next cell with no action, or else we move to the next case.

We check the case that three cells to the left matches any of the check strings - if so we duck out of the select case and move on to the next cell with no action, or else we move to the case else.

Only if none of the cells between one and 3 to the left of the cell we're checking have matched to any of the strings to check against, we then run the if statement and apply the formatting if it evaluates to true.